# Preserve State of Pushed Radio Buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ransack

How would one go about preserving the state of a "pushed" radio button after running a search? I'm using the Ransack gem to generate this search.

View:

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>

  <strong>Location</strong></br>

  <%= radio_button_tag("q[location_cont]", "Kentucky") %>
  <%= label_tag "Kentucky" %></br></br>

  <%= radio_button_tag("q[location_cont]", "Kansas") %>
  <%= label_tag "Kansas" %></br></br>

  <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def index
  @search = Job.search(params[:q])
  @jobs = @search.result
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using `form_tag`, then `radio_button_tag` would be a valid field type to use.  And you could use the third parameter to indicate if the button is selected or not:

```
<%= radio_button_tag("q[location_cont]", "Kentucky", params[:q] && params[:q][:location_cont] == "Kentucky") %>
<%= label_tag "Kentucky" %></br></br>

<%= radio_button_tag("q[location_cont]", "Kansas", params[:q] && params[:q][:location_cont] == "Kansas") %>
<%= label_tag "Kansas" %></br></br>
```

Since you are using the Ransack `search_form_for`, then you want to use `radio_button` and I think you'd want something like this:

```
<%= f.radio_button(:location_cont, "Kentucky") %>
<%= f.label :location_cont, "Kentucky", value: "Kentucky" %></br></br>

<%= f.radio_button(:location_cont, "Kansas") %>
<%= f.label :location_cont, "Kansas", value: "Kansas" %></br></br>
```